# Перевод с С++ на Си

Tags: c, массивы

Только недавно начала изучать си, помогите, пожалуйста, перевести с С++ на Си.
Условие: На листке в клетку размером 10 × 10 выбрали какую-то клетку и, начиная от нее, стали
закрашивать подряд клетки, двигаясь только вниз и вправо. Затем первую и последнюю
закрашенную клетку стерли. Ваша задача — восстановить их. Если вариантов ответа несколько,
выведите любой.

Формат входного файла
Входные данные состоят из 10 строк, содержащих по 10 чисел 0 и 1. Число 0 означает
незакрашенную клетку, а 1 — закрашенную.
Формат выходных данных
Выведите изображение листка в том же формате, что и во входных данных, только с
добавлением первой и последней покрашенных клеток.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
    vector <vector <int> > a(10, vector <int>(10));
    pair <int, int> b[2];
    bool flag = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            cin >> a[i][j];
            if (a[i][j] == 1 && flag) {
                b[0].first = i; b[0].second = j;
                flag = false;
            }
            if (a[i][j] == 1) {
                b[1].first = i; b[1].second = j;
            }
        }
    }
    if (b[0].first > 0) {
        a[b[0].first - 1][b[0].second] = 1;
    }
    else {
        a[b[0].first][b[0].second - 1] = 1;
    }
    if (b[1].first < 9) {
        a[b[1].first + 1][b[1].second] = 1;
    }
    else {
        a[b[1].first][b[1].second + 1] = 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << a[i][0];
        for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
            cout << ' ' << a[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Код работает верно, помогите с переводом на си.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    vector <vector <int> > a(10, vector <int>(10));
    pair <int, int> b[2];
    bool flag = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            scanf("%d", a[i][j]);
            if (a[i][j] == 1 && flag) {
                b[0].first = i; b[0].second = j;
                flag = false;
            }
            if (a[i][j] == 1) {
                b[1].first = i; b[1].second = j;
            }
        }
    }
    if (b[0].first > 0) {
        a[b[0].first - 1][b[0].second] = 1;
    }
    else {
        a[b[0].first][b[0].second - 1] = 1;
    }
    if (b[1].first < 9) {
        a[b[1].first + 1][b[1].second] = 1;
    }
    else {
        a[b[1].first][b[1].second + 1] = 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d", a[i][0]);
        for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Я частично перевела, но не до конца понимаю, как оформить

Comment: "_частично_"  это как? В чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: @Павел Ериков есть строчки, которые я не знаю, как перевести на си  и от этого программа не работает. Первые 2 строчки от int main() вызывают затруднение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аналога `vector` и `pair` в си лично я не знаю, но они вам в этой задачи и не нужны.

Я заметил, что создавая матрицу через `vector<vector<int>>` вы не использовали никаких дополнительных функций по типу `push_back` и т.д. И по условию задачи размерность матрицы не изменяется.

Значит можно использовать самый обычный статический массив:

```
int arr[10][10];
```

И на строчке

```
scanf("%d", a[i][j]);
```

Перед `a[i][j]` нужно добавить `&` :)

Теперь насчет `pair`. Можно реализовать двумя способами:

1. Просто сделать статический массив из 4-х элементов, и в самом коде писать не `b[0].first`, а `b[0]`, не `b[1].second`, а `b[3]`.
2. Или можно написать самому структуру `cpair`.

   Например так:

   ```
   struct cpair {
       int first;
       int second;
   };
   ```

   И аналогично коду на `c++` сделать статический массив из 2 элементов типа `cpair`.

   ```
   struct cpair b[2];
   ```

   И тогда в самом коде ничего связанного с `b` можно не менять.

Comment: Спасибо, переделала, как вы сказали, все работает)